# Drop down menu showing up in top left of page

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm work on this [website](http://www.adamlowe.org/) and am trying to add drop down functionality. The theme is David Airey and I'm using the drop down functionality from twentyten. Pasted the CSS from twenty ten into the menu.css in David Airey, but when you hover over "Broadcast" (the only one utilizing drop down), the box appears in the top left. Checked everything thrice, but can't find where it's screwing up, an extra set of eyes could probably help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative` to `.nav li`.

This will make the submenu be absolutely positioned *relative* to the `li`, instead of the window.

A diagram is here: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative` to the `<li>` that contains the submenu.